# Android Class JsonRequest and Subclasses JsonRequestArray and JsonRequestObject

Tags: java, android, android-volley

May be my question is bit naive, as I am pretty new to Andorid. I am trying to use the class JsonRequestArray to send a GET request. I want to send some parameters with the request. I found some of the answers saying to make customRequest. However I want to use JsonRequestArray class only. From [Androids tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json) its seems that we need to pass something to constructor in place of null here:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

But its not clear that what should be the format of the paramater to set parameters. I tried to search for constructor of the class's JSONObjectArray but couldn't find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately the android-volley does not have a documentation source or atleast not one I could find. So I went to the source code at this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java).

The following is one of the constructor methods and you can pass the parameters in jsonRequest.

```
JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest,
                        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Let me know if you need any more help with this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think we can use post method also here. Right? Just for confirming, if I want to pass two parameters to p1 and p1. Then my call should be something like this:
JSONArray postPara = new JSONArray({"p1":"value1", "p2":"value2"});

JsonArrayRequest(method, url, postPara, listener, errorListener);

Comment: Better off using the put() method in jsonObject then calling toJSONArray(). Refer to the doc here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can refer to the following JavaDoc content:

```
    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param method the HTTP method to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
     *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }
```

If you use mcxiaoke's Volley instead of Google's one, you will then have other constructors, such as:

```
    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param method the HTTP method to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param requestBody A {@link String} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
     *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
                             Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener,
                errorListener);
    }
```